# For UDP sockets, is the ip address unbounded the moment close() returns?

Tags: c, sockets, binding, port, bind

While reading [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388706/socket-options-so-reuseaddr-and-so-reuseport-how-do-they-differ-do-they-mean-t) i learned that a TCP socket can have a state called `TIME_WAIT`. Due to that state, it is possible that the TCP socket hasn't released the address it has been bonded to, even though the `close(int fd)` function returned  `0`.

Given that UDP is connectionless and it doesn't have reliability requirements to deliver the data like TCP, is it safe to assume that once the `close(int fd)` returns `0`, the address is unbound?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, according to the source code https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/ipv4/udp.c?id=refs/tags/v3.19-rc6, `udp_destroy_sock()` (~line 2028) flushes any pending frames, and releases the socket which frees the address.

You can demonstrate this with a simple example. You'll need `netcat`, a client and a server.  One the server, run this code:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    struct sockaddr_in me;
    int sock;

    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1) {
        perror("socket error:");
        return -1;
        }
    memset(&me, 0, sizeof(me));
    me.sin_family = AF_INET;
    me.sin_port = htons(60000);
    me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&me, sizeof(me)) == -1) {
        perror("bind error: ");
        return -1;
        }

    printf("On client execute:\n");
    printf("      nc -u {servers ip address} 60000\n\n");
    printf("type: hello world<enter>\n");
    printf("Hit enter when you've done this...");
    getchar();

    printf("\nNow check the input queue on this server\n");
    printf("    netstat -an|grep 60000\n");
    printf("Notice that we have buffered data we have not read\n");
    printf("(probably about 360 bytes)\n");
    printf("Hit enter to continue...");
    getchar();

    printf("\nI'm going to end. After I do, run netstat -an again\n");
    printf("and you'll notice port 60000 is gone.\n\n");
    printf("Re-run this program on server again and see you\n");
    printf("have no problem re-acquiring the UDP port.\n");
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Can you add a code example (which can be ran) how it showing that a scenarion in which TCP wouldn't release the address on socket close while UDP would?

Comment: I think it's needless to showcase the TIME_WAIT state of a TCP socket since it's a state mandated by the specs, it's documented pretty much everywhere and the Linux kernel includes tunables to affect it's duration. A socket always enters the TIME_WAIT state when terminated normally.

Comment: I think the OP was trying to confirm that a UDP port was completely released when the acquirer process ended. I agree that that the linux kernel reference was the authoritative answer, but he was looking for a little more confidence this was true -- a way to test.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** UDP sockets will be closed and unbound immediately (unless its a broadcast/multicast address with other listeners).

TIME WAIT is specified by the original [RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793) **and applies to TCP only**. It requires a 2 * Maximum Segment Lifetime to expire before closing the socket in TCP.

The famous [Unix Network Programming](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=ptSC4LpwGA0C&lpg=PA43&ots=Ks2zUmjnTm&dq=UDP%20TIME_WAIT&pg=PA43#v=onepage&q=UDP%20TIME_WAIT&f=false) by Stevens also explains TCP's TIME WAIT in more detail for the curious.

UDP does not have connections.. **TIME WAIT is not part of that protocol.**

The Linux source whilst relevant for potentially proprietary behaviour on Linux based systems is not the authority on such matters.

The original 1981 DARPA TCP [RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793) is authoritative as well as the [Berkeley Sockets api](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) on which [POSIX sockets](https://www2.opengroup.org/ogsys/jsp/publications/PublicationDetails.jsp?publicationid=11231) are based define the expected behaviour of the sockets API.

Also relevant is the [BSD network stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution) which powered TCP/IP in the early internet through to Windows, iOS, and OSX today and provides the authoritative reference implementation of the TCP/IP RFCs.  The BSD stack is still regarded as [the benchmark for a future Linux stack several years from now.](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTc1NjY) (Facebook posted a role mid 2014 for an expert to help make Linux match or exceed the reliability and performance of the FreeBSD stack).